# How do I further expand my restored principal menu?

Tags: 7

By mistake I eliminated the entire principal menu.

I already restored it but it appears with all the sub menus.
I need to change it but I don't know how to make the expanding menu.

Comment: There is an "expanded" option for each menu item so checking that might help. Are you using a module like nice_menus or something. This really depends on how your menu was originally done. Restoring from a backup may be the easiest solution.